# How to integrate captcha bypass using 2captcha api in Python Selenium

Tags: python, api, selenium, recaptcha, 2captcha

I'm making a reddit account auto-generator. I want to ask how can I use 2captcha's api to bypass recaptcha. Because after entering the username and password, the new captcha box appears, I have researched on the 2captcha page, the video tutorials on youtube but still have not found a way. Thanks everyone and have a nice day!

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import time
import openpyxl
import requests
import pandas as pd
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

solver = TwoCaptcha('YOUR_API_KEY')

# Load the Excel file
...
# Loop through the rows of the DataFrame
...
   # Get the latest IP address from the proxy service
   ...
   # Update the capabilities object to use the new proxy
   ...
   # Create a new instance of the webdriver with the updated capabilities
   # Use selenium to signup with the username and password
   
   result = solver.recaptcha(sitekey='6LeTnxkTAAAAAN9QEuDZRpn90WwKk_R1TRW_g-JC',
   url='https://www.reddit.com/account/register/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the TwoCaptcha documentation!

```
# Import the required libraries
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

# Create a new TwoCaptcha solver object
solver = TwoCaptcha('YOUR_API_KEY')

# Solve the reCAPTCHA on the Reddit signup page
result = solver.recaptcha(sitekey='6LeTnxkTAAAAAN9QEuDZRpn90WwKk_R1TRW_g-JC',
                         url='https://www.reddit.com/account/register/')

# Check the result to see if the reCAPTCHA was successfully solved
if result['status'] == 0:
    # Success
else:
    # Error
```